# Expand all PrimeNG Accordion panels automatically for Printing

Tags: css, angular, typescript, media-queries, primeng

I am currently using the PrimeNG library's accordion component in my angular project. [See info here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/accordion).

The template includes some special css styling for printing the page--something like the following:

```
 @media print {
  .profile-progress-bar, .top-template-header-content, .header.profile-header{
    display: none !important;
  }
  html, body {
    height: auto;
    font-size: 10px !important;
  }

  p-accordionTab > div {
    display: block !important;
    selected: true !important;
  }

}
```

What I am trying to do, is automatically expand all `accordionTab` elements when the `@media print` rendering is processed for the page to be printed.

From the documentation I see that each `accordionTab` element has a `[selected]` property which can be bound to and set to "true" in order to expand the tab.

> Selected Visibility of the content is specified with the selected
>   property that supports one or two-way binding.

However, can this be somehow automatically triggered when the `@media print` rendering occurs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

media query is the way to go, you can take a css only approach to achieve this; no change in TS or HTML files

relevant **css**:

```
@media print {
  ::ng-deep .ui-accordion-content-wrapper-overflown {
      overflow: visible;
      height: auto !important;
  }
}
```

complete [demo on stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h4rwsl)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting one. To keep it inside the realm of Angular, you could use the `@angular/cdk/layout` library and inject `MediaMatcher`.  You could also, of course, do almost this exact same thing using JavaScript (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList)... the cdk/layout method I'll show you really just wraps this).

The `MediaMatcher` service has a method called `matchMedia`, and from there you just add a listener:

```
import { MediaMatcher } from '@angular/cdk/layout';

constructor(private readonly mediaMatcher: MediaMatcher ) { }

ngOnInit() {
    mediaMatcher.matchMedia('print').addListener(e => e.matches ? 
    console.log('printing!') : null);
}
```

So where I've put the `console.log`, just perform your logic to get the accordians to expand.